# Concatenate environment variable in Apache RequestHeader

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-headers

Background: I am trying to set an Authorization header from my Apache VirtualHost config when a JWT is sent as a query parameter.

---

I am really close to getting this to work, but I have run into one final issue. The header must be in the form of:

> Authorization: Bearer **token**

Here is the relevant config I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} jwt=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=JWT:%1]
RequestHeader setifempty Authorization "Bearer %{JWT}e"
```

It ALMOST works, however, the header is set like so:

> Authorization: ('Bearer ' '**token**')

How can I make it so that the value of the header is concatenated into a single string without the parentheses and separate strings?

Comment: Did you solve that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to get this to work and I had to change the way I made the request.